# Are recursive boost-spirit grammars allowed?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am about to write a parser for a mathematica-like language and have found out, that it would be nice to sometimes invoke my spirit grammar for subparts of the expression to parse.

i.e. If I am about to parse

```
a+b*c+d
```

it would be handy to call `parse()` on the 'b*c' part while querying the '+' sign.

Is this possible to do while using the **same** instance of my grammar? (The grammar parameter would be '*this')

Though I am not yet fully convinced whether this is the best way to accomplish this particular task, I find the question rather interesting, since I could not find anything in the docs.

Obvously I should not depend on class-local or global variables if I used this technique. But I would like to know if it is principally allowed by the design of spirit.

**EDIT**:

My grammar instances look as follows:

```
class MyGrammar : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<...>  
{  
    /* a few rules. Some with local and/or inherited attributes */  
    MyGrammar( void )  
    {
         /* assign all the rules, use a few 'on_error' statements */
         // In one or two rules I would like to invoke parse(...,*this,...)  
         // on a subrange of the expression
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a highly non-specific question with a meaningless code snippet. Why don't you start with the samples in the documentation: http://boost-spirit.com/home/doc/

Comment: @sehe How is this non-specific? I want to know if boost-spirit supports recursive calls to parse() with the same grammar instance. (Yes or no)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
// In one or two rules I would like to invoke parse(...,*this,...)  
// on a subrange of the expression
```

^ That is not how rules are composed in a declarative grammar. You seem to think of this in procedural terms (which may indicate you could have previous experience writing recursive-descent parsers?).

---

Off the top of my mind a simple expression grammar in spirit could look like this:

```
  literal     = +qi::int_;
  variable    = lexeme [ qi::alpha >> *qi::alnum ];
  term        =  literal 
               | variable 
               | (qi::lit('(') > expression >> ')');

  factor      = term >> *(qi::char_("+-") >> term);
  expression  = factor >> *(qi::char_("*/%") >> term);
```

Note the recursion in the last branch of `term`: it parsers parenthesized expressions.

This simplistic sample won't actually result in a parse tree that reflects operator precedence. But the samples and tests in the Spirit library contain ***many*** examples that do.

See also other answers of mine that show how this works in more detail (with full samples):

- [Boost::Spirit Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464969/boostspirit-expression-parser/8468822#8468822)

  *A fullblown example with links to documentation samples and explanations of improvements of the original code by the asker*
- [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598)
- [Compilation error with a boost::spirit parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453712/compilation-error-with-a-boostspirit-parser/9458029#9458029) yet another approach

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I actually ended up implementing it using plain rules. (It was easier than I first thought) - But nevertheless. You answered the question!