# Compilation error on ambiguous type in code using boost::spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-variant

If I write this code it still compiles:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

struct STreeConstructionRuleQuery : std::string {};
struct STreeConstructionRuleOperation : std::string {};
struct STreeConstructionRuleOperand : std::string {};
struct STreeConstructionRuleCondition : std::string {};

struct STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands : boost::tuple<STreeConstructionRuleOperation, std::vector<STreeConstructionRuleOperand> > {};

struct STreeConstructionRule
{
    boost::optional<std::vector<std::vector<STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> > > m_sAssertion;
    STreeConstructionRuleQuery m_sQuery;
    STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands m_sAction;
    boost::optional<STreeConstructionRuleCondition> m_sCondition;
};

}


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRule,
    (boost::optional<std::vector<std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> > >, m_sAssertion)
    (MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleQuery, m_sQuery)
    (MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands, m_sAction)
    (boost::optional<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleCondition>, m_sCondition)
)


namespace MyNamespace
{

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

template <typename Iterator>
struct STreeContructionRulesGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<STreeConstructionRule>(), ascii::space_type>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<STreeConstructionRule>(), ascii::space_type> m_oStart;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::unused_type(), ascii::space_type> m_oComment;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRule(), ascii::space_type> m_oRule;

    STreeContructionRulesGrammar() : STreeContructionRulesGrammar::base_type(m_oStart)
    {
        m_oStart = *(m_oComment | m_oRule [phoenix::push_back(qi::_val, qi::_1)]);
        m_oComment = (("-->" >> *(qi::char_) >> "<--") | ('#' >> *(qi::char_ - qi::char_("\n\r")))); 
    }

};
}
```

But when I change the definition of `STreeConstructionRuleOperand` to

```
struct STreeConstructionRuleOperand : boost::variant<int> {};
```

I get the following compilation error (STLPort is used instead of STL):

```
1>d:\commonlib\include\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1373) : error C2666: 'boost::variant<T0_>::convert_construct' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T0_=int
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1358): could be 'void boost::variant<T0_>::convert_construct<int,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>(const boost::variant<T0_> &,long)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T0_=int
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1289): or       'void boost::variant<T0_>::convert_construct<const T>(T &,int,boost::mpl::false_)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T0_=int,
1>            T=MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperand
1>        ]
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(const MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperand, long)'
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\fusion\container\vector\detail\vector_n.hpp(45) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::variant<T0_>::variant<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperand>(const T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T0_=int,
1>            T=MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperand
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\_uninitialized.h(93) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void stlpd_std::_Destroy_Range<_OutputIter>(_ForwardIterator,_ForwardIterator)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutputIter=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *,
1>            _ForwardIterator=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\_uninitialized.h(113) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutputIter stlpd_std::priv::__ucopy<_InputIter,_OutputIter,ptrdiff_t>(_RandomAccessIter,_RandomAccessIter,_OutputIter,const stlpd_std::random_access_iterator_tag &,_Distance *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutputIter=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *,
1>            _InputIter=const stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *,
1>            _RandomAccessIter=const stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *,
1>            _Distance=ptrdiff_t
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\_vector.h(249) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutputIter stlpd_std::priv::__ucopy_ptrs<const stlpd_std::vector<_Tp>*,stlpd_std::vector<_Tp>*>(_InputIter,_InputIter,_OutputIter,const stlpd_std::__false_type &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutputIter=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *,
1>            _Tp=MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands,
1>            _InputIter=const stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> *
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\_vector.h(246) : while compiling class template member function 'stlpd_std::priv::_NonDbg_vector<_Tp,_Alloc>::_NonDbg_vector(const stlpd_std::priv::_NonDbg_vector<_Tp,_Alloc> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tp=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>,
1>            _Alloc=stlpd_std::allocator<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\debug\_iterator.h(378) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stlpd_std::priv::_NonDbg_vector<_Tp,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tp=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>,
1>            _Alloc=stlpd_std::allocator<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\stlport\stl\debug\_vector.h(106) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stlpd_std::priv::__construct_checker<_Container>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Container=stlpd_std::priv::_NonDbg_vector<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>,stlpd_std::allocator<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\optional\optional.hpp(110) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stlpd_std::vector<_Tp>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tp=stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\optional\optional.hpp(113) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::aligned_storage<T>::dummy_u' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=stlpd_std::vector<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\optional\optional.hpp(450) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::aligned_storage<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=stlpd_std::vector<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\commonlib\include\boost\optional\optional.hpp(457) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=stlpd_std::vector<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
1>        d:\preformator\sources\prefcore\preftreeconstructor.cpp(52) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=stlpd_std::vector<stlpd_std::vector<MyNamespace::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands>>
1>        ]
```

This is the only error the compiler reports. I don't see any ambiguity but the compiler does. What is the reason for this error and how it should be fixed?

Comment: Have you asked for support from the spirit team directly? see [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/feedback-and-support/)

Comment: No... Does it look like bug in spirit?

Comment: @coproc that's not supposed to happen, really. We do spirit answers here, especially since this looks to be unrelated to spirit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things strike me here:

1. how would something that is used to be `std::string`, be assigned to something that is a now a `variant<int>`?

   The code shown doesn't include the code that would explain this (as it is probably in `m_oRule` or a subrule of that).  But perhaps a `variant<std::string>` poses fewer problems, seeing how you had a `std::string` value to assign before.
2. You appear to *abuse* `struct` *inheritance* quite a lot to achieve `typedef` behaviour. Note that public inheritance is **not** the same as a `typedef`, especially with regards to the *constructors* (which are **not** inherited).

   Try replacing each use of

   ```
   struct A : baseType {};
   ```

   by the more usual idiom of

   ```
   typedef baseType A;
   ```

I actually expect the latter to solve the issue, since you are running into constructor overload trouble.

Regardless of that, I have only tested with gcc, boost_1_51_0 and GNU libstdc++. It compiles everything you posted without a hitch (but again, not you left out crucial elements, such as the *rule* `m_oRule` that does the actual assigning to `RuleOpWithOperands`).

#### Demonstration FauxTypedef:

Demonstrating the relevant problem (at least one) with *inheritance* instead of `typedef`:

```
struct Type {
    Type(int, double) { }
};

typedef Type          ProperTypedef;
struct  FauxTypedef : Type { };

int main()
{
    Type          a(1, 4.2); // okay
    ProperTypedef b(1, 4.2); // okay as well, obviously
    FauxTypedef   c(1, 4.2); // oops ouch!!! This won't compile
}
```

If you insist on having a _unique `typeid` for the typedef-ed name, you can resort to [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)

Comment: Adding a demonstration + mention of [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)

Comment: Answers: 1. it wasn't supposed to have type `std::string` or `boost::variant<int>`. Those types were used to show the issue. 2. Thank you for your note, I've used `struct SBlah` for forward definition. Those structs are used in `boost::recursive_wrapper<SBlah>`. I mean I need rules like these: `SConcatenation ::= SIteration*; SIteration ::= (std::string | '(' SConcatenation ')' ('*'|'+'|'?')? );`. Is it possible to archive such definition without using inheritance?

Comment: @user1621097 The code you showed had no forward declares, nor boost::variant. There is absolutely **no** need to use forward declares for classes that will not contain recursive references.

Comment: @user1621097 Anyways, for good examples doing precisely what you describe (expression parsing with (subexpressions)) see e.g. **[bool expression parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598)**, [Are recursive boost-spirit grammars allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616766/are-recursive-boost-spirit-grammars-allowed/12622808#12622808) (the latter has links to more examples). Also see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc1.cpp and other samples there