# Building a Custom Expression Tree in Spirit:Qi (Without Utree or Boost::Variant)

Tags: c++, parsing, expression-trees, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

First of all, if it is much easier using either Boost Variant or Utree, then I will settle with them, and i will try to solve my issues with them in another topic. However, i would very much like to be able to build a tree like i have below.

Background, ignore if you would like to go straight to the issue: I would like to be able to build an expression tree which parses something like

```
"({a} == 0) && ({b} > 5)"
```

or a standard mathmatic expression

```
"(2 * a) + b"
```

I will then define what a and b are before i evaluate my tree, something like this:

```
a = 10;
double val = myExpression->Evaluate();
```

My issue comes from when i try to build the try to parse the string into my Expression Tree. I am using an abstract class "Expression" which then derives "Variable", "Constant" and "Binary" expressions (it will also do unary, but it shouldnt effect my problem. I keep having problems with adding to the tree using my rules, so im clearly doing something wrong. Im having a hard time wrapping my head around the attributes.

My Tree is as follows (Tree.h):

```
class BinaryExpression;
typedef double (*func)(double, double);

class Expression
{
public:
    virtual double Evaluate() = 0;
};

class BinaryExpression : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression* lhs;
    Expression* rhs;
    func method;

    double Evaluate();

public:
    BinaryExpression(void);
    BinaryExpression(char op, Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs);
    BinaryExpression(char op);
    void operator()(Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs);
};

class ConstantExpression : public Expression
{
private:
    double value;
public:
    ConstantExpression(void);
    ConstantExpression(char op);
    ConstantExpression(double val);

    double Evaluate();
};

// Require as many types as there are fields in expression?
static double a;
static double b;
class VariableExpression : public Expression
{
private:
    char op;

public:
    VariableExpression(char op);

    double Evaluate();
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    BinaryExpression,
    (Expression*, lhs)
    (Expression*, rhs)
    (func, method)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    VariableExpression,
    (char, op)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    ConstantExpression,
    (double, op)
)
```

Tree.cpp

```
typedef double (*func)(double, double);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BINARY EXPRESSION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression(void) {}

BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression(char op, Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs)
{
    this->lhs = lhs;
    this->rhs = rhs;

    // Example, methods are held in another header
    if (op == '+')
        method = Add;
    else if (op == '-')
        method = Subtract;

}

double BinaryExpression::Evaluate()
{
    return method(lhs->Evaluate(), rhs->Evaluate());
}

BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression(char op)
{
    if (op == '+')
        method = Add;
    else if (op == '-')
        method = Subtract;
}

void BinaryExpression::operator()(Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs)
{
    this->lhs = lhs;
    this->rhs = rhs;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CONSTANT EXPRESSION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ConstantExpression::ConstantExpression() {}

ConstantExpression::ConstantExpression(char op)
{
    this->value = op - 48;
}
ConstantExpression::ConstantExpression(double val)
{
    value = val;
}

double ConstantExpression::Evaluate()
{
    return value;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VARIABLE EXPRESSION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

VariableExpression::VariableExpression(char op)
{
    this->op = op;
}

double VariableExpression::Evaluate()
{
    // a and b are defined in the header, and are used to fill in the variables we     want to evaluate
    if (op == 'a')
        return a;
    if (op == 'b')
        return b;
    return 0;
}
```

Now if i build the tree manually it all works fine, so i dont think theres an issue with the way it is structured.

Here is Grammar.h (Lots of comments from where i tried various things, i could remove them, but i may be worth showing what i've tried / where i want to go with it)

```
#include "Tree.h"

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

qi::_1_type _1;
qi::_2_type _2;

// Pass functions to boost
boost::phoenix::function<BinaryExpression> plus = BinaryExpression('+');
boost::phoenix::function<BinaryExpression> minus = BinaryExpression('-');

template <typename Iterator>
struct ExpressionParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, BinaryExpression(), ascii::space_type>
{
    ExpressionParser() : ExpressionParser::base_type(expression)
    {
        qi::_3_type _3;
        qi::_4_type _4;

        qi::char_type char_;
        qi::uint_type uint_;
        qi::_val_type _val;
        qi::raw_type raw;
        qi::lexeme_type lexeme;
        qi::alpha_type alpha;
        qi::alnum_type alnum;
        qi::bool_type bool_;
        qi::double_type double_;


        expression = //?
            additive_expr                       [_val = _1]
            ;

        //equality_expr = 
        //      relational_expr >> 
        //      *(lit("==") > relational_expr)      [/*Semantice action to add to tree*/]
        //      ;

        additive_expr =
            primary_expr >>
            ( '+' > primary_expr)               [plus(_val, _1)]   
            | ( '-' > primary_expr)             [minus(_val, _1)]
            ;
        // Also tried "_val = plus(_1, _2)"

        primary_expr =
            constant                                [_val = _1]
            | variable                          [_val = _1]
            //| '(' > expression > ')'          [_val = _1]
            ;

        string %=
            '{' >> *(char_ - '}') >> '}'
            ;

        // Returns ConstantExpression
        constant =
            double_                                 [_val = _1];

        // Returns VariableExpression
        variable =
            char_                                   [_val = _1]
            ;
    }

    // constant expression = double
    // variable expression = string
    qi::rule<Iterator, BinaryExpression(), ascii::space_type>
        expression;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BinaryExpression(), ascii::space_type>
        // eventually will deal with all these rules
        equality_expr,
        relational_expr,        
        logical_expr,
        additive_expr,
        multiplicative_expr,
        primary_expr
            ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, ConstantExpression(), ascii::space_type>
        constant
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, VariableExpression(), ascii::space_type>
        variable
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type>
        string
        ;
};
```

So this is a really hacked apart, but hopefully it will show what im trying to achieve. Any advice or tips would be really appreciated. Is there an example where someone has built a tree like this without using variant or utree.

Also sorry if ive broken convention, and for my formatting, i tried to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't clear to me what your gripe with (recursive) variants are, but here is a variation that goes along with your wish to use 'old fashioned' tree building using dynamically allocated nodes:

- http://liveworkspace.org/code/3VS77n$0

I have purposefully sidestepped the issue of *operator precedence* in your grammar because

- your grammar was incomplete
- I don't know the desired semantics (after all, you appear to support boolean evaluation as well, but I'm not sure how)
- You can learn about these in other answers:

  - [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598)
  - [Boost::Spirit Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464969/boostspirit-expression-parser/8468822#8468822)
  - [Compilation error with a boost::spirit parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453712/compilation-error-with-a-boostspirit-parser/9458029#9458029) shows an alternative approach

Note how I

- removed ubiquitous memory leaks by using shared_ptr (you can use the *Boost* one if you don't have a TR1 library)
- I removed the misguided reuse of a specific BinaryExpression instance as a *phoenix lazy actor*. Instead I made a local `makebinary` actor now.
- Note how chains of operators (1+2+5+6-10) are now supported:

  ```
  additive_expr =
      primary_expr                         [ _val = _1 ]
      >> *(char_("-+*/") >> primary_expr)  [ _val = makebinary(_1, _val, _2)]
      ;
  ```
- I added `{var}`, `/`, `*` and `(expr)` support
- added serialization for display (`Print` virtual method, `operator<<`) (for display convenience, BinaryExpression stores the `operator` instead of the resultant `method` now)
- Therefore now you can use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG (uncomment first line)
- I have renamed `Expression` to `AbstractExpression` (and made de constructor *protected*)
- I have renamed `PrimaryExpression` to `Expression` (and this is now your main *expression datatype*)
- I show how to store simplistically variables in a `static` map

  - be sure to have a look at `qi::symbols` and
  - e.g. [How to add qi::symbols in grammar<Iterator,double()>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780604/how-to-add-qisymbols-in-grammariterator-double/8781537#8781537)
- Uses far less *fusion struct adaptation* (only for `variable` now)
- Uses the templated constructor trick to make it very easy to construct an expression from disparate parsed types:

  ```
  struct Expression : AbstractExpression {
      template <typename E>
      Expression(E const& e) : _e(make_from(e)) { } // cloning the expression
      // ...
  };
  ```

  is enough to *efficiently* support e.g.:

  ```
  primary_expr =
        ( '(' > expression > ')' )         [ _val = _1 ]
      | constant                           [ _val = _1 ]
      | variable                           [ _val = _1 ]
      ;
  ```
- for fun have included a few more test cases:

  ```
  Input:                3*8 + 6
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(3) * ConstantExpression(8)) + ConstantExpression(6)))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    30
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                3*(8+6)
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(3) * BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(8) + ConstantExpression(6))))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    42
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                0x1b
  Expression:           Expression(ConstantExpression(27))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    27
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                1/3
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(1) / ConstantExpression(3)))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    0.333333
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                .3333 * 8e12
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(0.3333) * ConstantExpression(8e+12)))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    2.6664e+12
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                (2 * a) + b
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(2) * VariableExpression('a')) + VariableExpression('b')))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               10, 7
  Evaluation result:    27
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                (2 * a) + b
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(2) * VariableExpression('a')) + VariableExpression('b')))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               -10, 800
  Evaluation result:    780
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                (2 * {a}) + b
  Expression:           Expression(BinaryExpression(BinaryExpression(ConstantExpression(2) * VariableExpression('a')) + VariableExpression('b')))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               -10, 800
  Evaluation result:    780
  ----------------------------------------
  Input:                {names with spaces}
  Expression:           Expression(VariableExpression('names with spaces'))
  Parse success:        true
  Remaining unparsed:  ''
  (a, b):               0, 0
  Evaluation result:    0
  ----------------------------------------
  ```

### [Full Code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3VS77n$0)

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
// #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct AbstractExpression;
typedef std::shared_ptr<AbstractExpression> Ptr;

struct AbstractExpression {
    virtual ~AbstractExpression() {}
    virtual double Evaluate() const = 0;
    virtual std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const = 0;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, AbstractExpression const& e)
        { return e.Print(os); }

    protected: AbstractExpression() {}
};

template <typename Expr> // general purpose, static Expression cloner
    static Ptr make_from(Expr const& t) { return std::make_shared<Expr>(t); }

struct BinaryExpression : AbstractExpression 
{
    BinaryExpression() {}

    template<typename L, typename R>
    BinaryExpression(char op, L const& l, R const& r) 
        : _op(op), _lhs(make_from(l)), _rhs(make_from(r)) 
    {}

    double Evaluate() const {
        func f = Method(_op);
        assert(f && _lhs && _rhs);
        return f(_lhs->Evaluate(), _rhs->Evaluate());
    }

  private:
    char _op;
    Ptr _lhs, _rhs;

    typedef double(*func)(double, double);

    static double Add(double a, double b)      { return a+b; }
    static double Subtract(double a, double b) { return a-b; }
    static double Multuply(double a, double b) { return a*b; }
    static double Divide(double a, double b)   { return a/b; }

    static BinaryExpression::func Method(char op)
    {
        switch(op) {
            case '+': return Add;
            case '-': return Subtract;
            case '*': return Multuply;
            case '/': return Divide;
            default:  return nullptr;
        }
    }
    std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const
        { return os << "BinaryExpression(" << *_lhs << " " << _op << " " << *_rhs << ")"; }
};

struct ConstantExpression : AbstractExpression {
    double value;
    ConstantExpression(double v = 0) : value(v) {}

    double Evaluate() const { return value; }

    virtual std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const
        { return os << "ConstantExpression(" << value << ")"; }
};

struct VariableExpression : AbstractExpression {
    std::string _name;

    static double& get(std::string const& name) {
        static std::map<std::string, double> _symbols;
        return _symbols[name];
        /*switch(name) {
         *    case 'a': static double a; return a;
         *    case 'b': static double b; return b;
         *    default:  throw "undefined variable";
         *}
         */
    }

    double Evaluate() const { return get(_name); }

    virtual std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const
        { return os << "VariableExpression('" << _name << "')"; }
};

struct Expression : AbstractExpression
{
    Expression() { }

    template <typename E>
    Expression(E const& e) : _e(make_from(e)) { } // cloning the expression

    double Evaluate() const { assert(_e); return _e->Evaluate(); }

    // special purpose overload to avoid unnecessary wrapping
    friend Ptr make_from(Expression const& t) { return t._e; }
  private:
    Ptr _e;
    virtual std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const
        { return os << "Expression(" << *_e << ")"; }
};

//Tree.cpp

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BINARY EXPRESSION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//#include "Tree.h"
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(VariableExpression, (std::string, _name))

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

// Pass functions to boost
template <typename Iterator>
struct ExpressionParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type> 
{
    struct MakeBinaryExpression {
        template<typename,typename,typename> struct result { typedef BinaryExpression type; };

        template<typename C, typename L, typename R>
            BinaryExpression operator()(C op, L const& lhs, R const& rhs) const 
            { return BinaryExpression(op, lhs, rhs); }
    };

    phx::function<MakeBinaryExpression> makebinary;

    ExpressionParser() : ExpressionParser::base_type(expression) 
    {
        using namespace qi;
        expression =
            additive_expr                        [ _val = _1]
            ;

        additive_expr =
            primary_expr                         [ _val = _1 ]
            >> *(char_("-+*/") >> primary_expr)  [ _val = makebinary(_1, _val, _2)]
            ;

        primary_expr =
              ( '(' > expression > ')' )         [ _val = _1 ]
            | constant                           [ _val = _1 ]
            | variable                           [ _val = _1 ]
            ;

        constant = lexeme ["0x" >> hex] | double_ | int_;
        string   = '{' >> lexeme [ *~char_("}") ] > '}';
        variable = string | as_string [ alpha ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expression);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(additive_expr);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(primary_expr);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(constant);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(variable);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(string);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, Expression()        , ascii::space_type> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Expression()        , ascii::space_type> additive_expr;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Expression()        , ascii::space_type> primary_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ConstantExpression(), ascii::space_type> constant;
    qi::rule<Iterator, VariableExpression(), ascii::space_type> variable;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()       , ascii::space_type> string;
};

void test(const std::string input, double a=0, double b=0)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    ExpressionParser<It> p;

    Expression e;
    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,ascii::space,e);

    std::cout << "Input:                "  << input            << "\n";
    std::cout << "Expression:           "  << e                << "\n";
    std::cout << "Parse success:        "  << std::boolalpha   << ok << "\n";
    std::cout << "Remaining unparsed:  '"  << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    std::cout << "(a, b):               "  << a << ", " << b   << "\n";

    VariableExpression::get("a") = a;
    VariableExpression::get("b") = b;
    std::cout << "Evaluation result:    "  << e.Evaluate()     << "\n";
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
}

int main() 
{
    test("3*8 + 6"); 
    test("3*(8+6)"); 
    test("0x1b"); 
    test("1/3"); 
    test(".3333 * 8e12");
    test("(2 * a) + b",    10,   7);
    test("(2 * a) + b",   -10, 800);
    test("(2 * {a}) + b", -10, 800);
    test("{names with spaces}");
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you! Sorry if i was not clear with my question but the issue was with the grammar (again sorry it was hacked apart from me trying different things, but i tried to get what i was trying to achieve across), and how you could go about building the tree in the structure defined.

"Uses the templated constructor trick to make it very easy to construct an expression from disparate parsed types:" solves most of the issues i had. 

Some of the methods are foreign to me, so I'm going to have to read up on them before continuing. Once again, thank you!